# Unable to display animated sprites from PokeAPI in Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, pokeapi

I am developing a Pokedex project using Angular.

I am fetching the PokeAPI successfully and I can display the regular sprites by writing:

```
<img [src]="pokemon[0].sprites.front_default" [alt]="pokemon[0].name" >
```

but when I try to display an animated gif in a different directory by writing:

```
[src]="pokemon[0].sprites.versions.generation-v.black-white.animated.front_default"
```

it throws me two errors stating:

> Property 'v' does not exist on type 'DetailsComponent'.
>
> Property 'white' does not exist on type 'DetailsComponent'.

This is happening because I have to parse a text containing a hyphen and Angular reads it as something else

**What would be the correct way of parsing the source of the image without having issues?**

Comment: "This is happening because I have to parse a text containing a hyphen and Angular reads it as something else" can you elaborate on this? And give a sample of the data?

Comment: In case the field names in your data contain hyphens, you can access the properties like this: `pokemon[0].sprites.versions['generation-v']['black-white'].animated.front_default`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you obtain the text for the image in your typescript file, save it in the variable, *pokemonImage*, and use the variable as the value for the [src] property. 
On your HTML page have something like this:
`<img id="imageOfPokemon" alt="{{pokemonName}}" src="{{pokemonImage}}" width="250" height="250"/>`. 
In your typescript file, create the property *pokemonImage: string = ''*, and save the following as the value:
`this.pokemonImage = pokemon['sprites']['versions']['generation-v']['black-white']['animated'].front_default;`